# Show that a wf $\mathscr{B}(t)⇒(\exists x_i)\mathscr{B}(x_i)$ logically valid if $t$ is free for $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic, exercise 2.18 asks us to show that certain wfs are logically valid. A wf `B` is said to be *logically valid* if and only if `B` is true for every interpretation.

Given the following wf:
[image]

Mendelson provides the following answer at the back of the book:
[image]

My question has to do with the first part of the answer. I understand how "By (X), $(∀x_i)\lnot \mathscr{B}(x_i)\rightarrow\lnot \mathscr{B}(t)$" is logically valid - this is because $\lnot\mathscr{B}(x_i)$ is also a wf from the definition of the language, right?

And, by (III), $\mathscr{B}(t)⇒\lnot(\forall x_i)\lnot\mathscr{B}(x_i)$ is logically valid - this is because as property (III) states, if $(∀x_i)\lnot \mathscr{B}(x_i)\rightarrow\lnot \mathscr{B}(t)$ is true for the interpretation $M$ and $[(\forall x_i)\lnot\mathscr{B}(x_i)\rightarrow\lnot\mathscr{B}(t)]\rightarrow[\mathscr{B}(t)\rightarrow\lnot(\forall x_i)¬\mathscr{B}(x_i)]$ then $\mathscr{B}(t)\rightarrow\lnot(\forall x_i)¬\mathscr{B}(x_i)$ is true for the interpretation $M$.

How though, does Mendelson's obtain $[(\forall x_i)\lnot\mathscr{B}(x_i)\rightarrow\lnot\mathscr{B}(t)]\rightarrow[\mathscr{B}(t)\rightarrow\lnot(\forall x_i)¬\mathscr{B}(x_i)]$ ? I understand that it is a tautology but I do not see how it is he comes to it?

If it is obvious that I've made a jump over a gap in knowledge any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With "I do not see how he comes to it", do you mean "I do not see why he says it's a tautology" or do you mean "I don't see how he came up with this idea"?

Comment: I haven't thought about why it's a tautology, but I can draw out the truth tables to prove it happily enough. What I meant in my question was "I don't see how he came up with this idea", thanks for clarifying

Comment: Every FOL instance of a tautology is *valid*. This means that, starting from a taut, like e.g. $A \lor \lnot A$, we can produce a valid formula simply replacing $A$ with a FOL formula whatever. Example $\forall x Px \lor \lnot \forall x Px$.

Comment: There are FOL valid formula that are **not** instances of tautologies, like e.g. $\forall x (x=x)$.

Comment: Is there a reason that he describes the tautology as $(A\rightarrow\lnot B)\rightarrow(B\rightarrow\lnot A)$ and not $(A\rightarrow\lnot B)\leftrightarrow(B\rightarrow\lnot A)$

Comment: I know that $(A\rightarrow\lnot B)\leftrightarrow(B\rightarrow\lnot A)$ is equivalent to $((A\rightarrow\lnot B)\rightarrow(B\rightarrow\lnot A)) \land ((B\rightarrow\lnot A)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow\lnot B))$ but just curious why chose entailment over equivalence...

Comment: Maybe just because that is what Mendelson needed for this particular case. He wants to prove something of the form $B \to \lnot A$ and does so by proving $A \to \lnot B$ and using this tautology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Mendelson is doing is the following:

- Realize that $\exists x_i. B(x_i)$ is equivalent to $\lnot \forall x_i. \lnot B(x_i)$;
- Prove $B(t) \implies \lnot \forall x_i. \lnot B(x_i)$ by proving its contraposition $\forall x_i. \lnot B(x_i) \implies \lnot B(t)$.

This second step is, of course, using that particular tautology.